# Como aumentar o numero de iterações de uma função no R?

Tags: r

Meu problema é o seguinte, quando realizo a regressão

```
>mod<-glm(y~a+b+c,family=gaussian(link="log"), data = matrix)
Warning message:
glm.fit: algoritmo não convergiu
> summary(mod1)
...
Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25
```

Para contornar isso fiz:

```
>mod1<-glm(y~a+b+c ,family=gaussian(link="log"), data = matrix)
Warning message:
glm.fit: algoritmo não convergiu
>mod1<-glm(y~a+b+c,start=coef(mod1),family=gaussian(link="log"), data = matrix)
>summary(mod1)
...
Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

Então, como faço para aumentar o de iterações para além dos 25?

Comment: Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Eu não teria como colocar todos os meus dada.frame aqui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quantidade máxima de interações é definido pela função `glm.control(epsilon = 1e-8, maxit = 25, trace = FALSE)`, assim o numero máximo de interações está definido, por padrão, como 25.
Para mudar-lo, como por exemplo para 42, tem que se chamar o argumento `control=` da função `glm`. Ficando assim:

```
 glm(y~a+b+c, control=glm.control(epsilon = 1e-8, maxit = 42, trace = FALSE),family=gaussian)
```